# Date comparison & filtering data from array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I have the following array of objects coming from MongoDB with TTL 29 days (assume array contains large number of objects)

```
array1 = [
  {
   _id: "391A", // unique id 
   appData: { key1: "12345", key2: "abcd", key3: "dskjf" },
   createdOn: ISODate("2020-05-03T05:22:26.326Z"),
   customerData: { fName: "stack", lName: "overflow" }
  },
  {
    _id: "485B", // unique id 
    appData: { key1: "ewrf", key2: "hgmjn", key3: "rdffd" },
    createdOn: ISODate("2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z"),
    customerData: { fName: "fd", lName: "xcv" }
  },
  {
     _id: "DFB5", // unique id 
     appData: { key1: "dfvf", key2: "hjhgg", key3: "sxxcxc" },
     createdOn: ISODate("2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z"),
     customerData: { fName: "vihn", lName: "jkmv" }
  }
];
```

I have another array of large objects which i convert to Map.
[ Assume startDate & endDate difference is 30 days ]

```
Map {
 "896J" => { startDate: "2020-04-30T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-05-30T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "961G" => { startDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "391A" => { startDate: "2020-04-30T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-05-30T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "BB86" => { startDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "NJ90" => { startDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "485B" => { startDate: "2020-02-14T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-03-15T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "KLP6" => { startDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z" },
}
```

I need to check whether the _id in array1 matches with large data in Map. If _id and Map key matches, then check in Map whether currentDate is less than or equal to (endDate - 1). Compare the date part only, time in date is not required. If check matches then create a new array of objects with the following output.

```
finalArray = [
 { createdAt: "startDateValue", key1: "12345", fName: "overflow"},
 { createdAt: "startDateValue", key1: "ewrf", fName: "fd"},
];
```

I am in the learning phase, so any help would be really appreciated. Moment or native javascript date is fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `key` in your final objects should be the `_id` from the `array1` objects right?

Comment: @OlivierKrull No, actually it will be appData.key1

Comment: currentDate meaning now or cratedOn?  startDateValue is just the literal string "startDateValue"?

Comment: @user120242 currentDate means now..startDateValue should be value of startDate in Map.

Comment: Should be a simple filter map.  You could probably get away with just truncating the date string and comparing it directly to avoid conversion overhead

Comment: @user120242 Yes but here we are not considering time, just need to compare date. It would be really greatful if you can post answer here.

Comment: Those dates look strange.  Are the month and day positions inconsistent?  You mention TTL but the dates are not within 29 days nor 30 days.

Comment: @user120242 Yes I have given dummy dates, actually this is response from service call, Mapping dates for "391A" and "485B" are correct. Assume the date difference will be 30 days...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple for loop:

```js
ISODate=Date;

var array1 = [
  {
   _id: "391A", // unique id 
   appData: { key1: "12345", key2: "abcd", key3: "dskjf" },
   createdOn: ISODate("2020-05-03T05:22:26.326Z"),
   customerData: { fName: "stack", lName: "overflow" }
  },
  {
    _id: "485B", // unique id 
    appData: { key1: "ewrf", key2: "hgmjn", key3: "rdffd" },
    createdOn: ISODate("2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z"),
    customerData: { fName: "fd", lName: "xcv" }
  },
  {
     _id: "DFB5", // unique id 
     appData: { key1: "dfvf", key2: "hjhgg", key3: "sxxcxc" },
     createdOn: ISODate("2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z"),
     customerData: { fName: "vihn", lName: "jkmv" }
  }
];

var map = new Map(Object.entries({
 "896J" : { startDate: "2020-04-30T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-05-30T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "961G" : { startDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "391A" : { startDate: "2020-04-30T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-05-30T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "BB86" : { startDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "NJ90" : { startDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "485B" : { startDate: "2020-02-14T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-03-15T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "KLP6" : { startDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z" },
}));


var now = new Date(new Date().getTime()+24*3600*1000).
            toISOString().slice(0,10);
var res = [];
for ( var i = 0 ; i < array1.length ; i++ ) {
  const x = array1[i];
  const y = map.get(x._id);
  if ( y && now < y.endDate )
    res.push({
     createdAt: y.startDate,
     key1: x.appData.key1, fName: x.customerData.fName
    });
}
console.log(res);
```

Reduce:

```js
ISODate=Date;

var array1 = [
  {
   _id: "391A", // unique id 
   appData: { key1: "12345", key2: "abcd", key3: "dskjf" },
   createdOn: ISODate("2020-05-03T05:22:26.326Z"),
   customerData: { fName: "stack", lName: "overflow" }
  },
  {
    _id: "485B", // unique id 
    appData: { key1: "ewrf", key2: "hgmjn", key3: "rdffd" },
    createdOn: ISODate("2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z"),
    customerData: { fName: "fd", lName: "xcv" }
  },
  {
     _id: "DFB5", // unique id 
     appData: { key1: "dfvf", key2: "hjhgg", key3: "sxxcxc" },
     createdOn: ISODate("2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z"),
     customerData: { fName: "vihn", lName: "jkmv" }
  }
];

var map = new Map(Object.entries({
 "896J" : { startDate: "2020-04-30T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-05-30T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "961G" : { startDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "391A" : { startDate: "2020-04-30T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-05-30T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "BB86" : { startDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "NJ90" : { startDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "485B" : { startDate: "2020-02-14T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-03-15T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "KLP6" : { startDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z" },
}));


var now = new Date(new Date().getTime()+24*3600*1000).
            toISOString().slice(0,10);

var res = array1.reduce( (res, x) => {
  const y = map.get(x._id);
  if ( y && now < y.endDate )
    res.push({
      createdAt: y.startDate,
      key1: x.appData.key1, fName: x.customerData.fName
    });
  return res;
},[]);

console.log(res);
```

flatMap version:

```js
ISODate=Date;

var array1 = [
  {
   _id: "391A", // unique id 
   appData: { key1: "12345", key2: "abcd", key3: "dskjf" },
   createdOn: ISODate("2020-05-03T05:22:26.326Z"),
   customerData: { fName: "stack", lName: "overflow" }
  },
  {
    _id: "485B", // unique id 
    appData: { key1: "ewrf", key2: "hgmjn", key3: "rdffd" },
    createdOn: ISODate("2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z"),
    customerData: { fName: "fd", lName: "xcv" }
  },
  {
     _id: "DFB5", // unique id 
     appData: { key1: "dfvf", key2: "hjhgg", key3: "sxxcxc" },
     createdOn: ISODate("2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z"),
     customerData: { fName: "vihn", lName: "jkmv" }
  }
];

var map = new Map(Object.entries({
 "896J" : { startDate: "2020-04-30T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-05-30T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "961G" : { startDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "391A" : { startDate: "2020-04-30T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-05-30T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "BB86" : { startDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "NJ90" : { startDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "485B" : { startDate: "2020-02-14T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-03-15T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "KLP6" : { startDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z" },
}));


var now = new Date(new Date().getTime()+24*3600*1000).
            toISOString().slice(0,10);
var res = array1.flatMap(x=> (y=map.get(x._id)) && now < y.endDate ? 
    {
     createdAt: y.startDate,
     key1: x.appData.key1, fName: x.customerData.lName
    } : []
); console.log(res);
```

Convert to integer for comparison:

```js
ISODate=Date;

var array1 = [
  {
   _id: "391A", // unique id 
   appData: { key1: "12345", key2: "abcd", key3: "dskjf" },
   createdOn: ISODate("2020-05-03T05:22:26.326Z"),
   customerData: { fName: "stack", lName: "overflow" }
  },
  {
    _id: "485B", // unique id 
    appData: { key1: "ewrf", key2: "hgmjn", key3: "rdffd" },
    createdOn: ISODate("2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z"),
    customerData: { fName: "fd", lName: "xcv" }
  },
  {
     _id: "DFB5", // unique id 
     appData: { key1: "dfvf", key2: "hjhgg", key3: "sxxcxc" },
     createdOn: ISODate("2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z"),
     customerData: { fName: "vihn", lName: "jkmv" }
  }
];

var map = new Map(Object.entries({
 "896J" : { startDate: "2020-04-30T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-05-30T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "961G" : { startDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "391A" : { startDate: "2020-04-30T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-05-30T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "BB86" : { startDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "NJ90" : { startDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "485B" : { startDate: "2020-02-14T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-03-15T05:22:26.326Z" },
 "KLP6" : { startDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z", endDate: "2020-12-03T05:22:26.326Z" },
}));

const datetoint = d => (d.slice(0,4)+d.slice(5,7)+d.slice(8,10))|0;

var now = datetoint(new Date(new Date().getTime()+24*3600*1000).
            toISOString().slice(0,10));
var res = [];
for ( var i = 0 ; i < array1.length ; i++ ) {
  const x = array1[i];
  const y = map.get(x._id);
  if ( y && now <= datetoint(y.endDate) )
    res.push({
     createdAt: y.startDate,
     key1: x.appData.key1, fName: x.customerData.fName
    });
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Do we need to do Object.freeze(array1) ?  Is there any specific reason behind the same?

Comment: No it's not necessary, and the optimization probably doesn't apply (I put in the link)

Comment: Can we use map instead of flatMap? Is there any reason behind using flatMap?

Comment: To combine filter and map into one operation

Comment: Some optimizations from a cursory look.  Depending on if the map is already created.  String comparison.  Slicing from position 2 to 10.   Although, if number of values isn't obscenely large to require more optimization, I'd just leave it at .map and .filter.  It'll be easier to read.  Might also want to test if `+(datestring.slice(2,10))|0` conversion to number and comparison might be faster.

Comment: simple for loop and reduce versions.  added convert date to int for comparison

Comment: sorry why you removed flapMap method?

Comment: I thought that it was causing problems with your code, or you didn't like the syntax.  I've added it back in.